# Flasgger: Swagger App - http://127.0.0.1:5000/apidocs/ - Fetch errorINTERNAL SERVER ERROR /apispec_1.json

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, swagger, flasgger

I created a Flasgger/Swagger App in Spyder and got returned:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2021 21:49:13] "GET /apispec_1.json HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2021 21:49:13] "GET /flasgger_static/favicon-32x32.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

When trying to visit this app in my Google Chrome browser via `http://127.0.0.1:5000/apidocs/` I got back this error:

```
Fetch error
INTERNAL SERVER ERROR /apispec_1.json
```

What do I have to change here?

Comment: If you are using the docstring on the endpoint make sure you are following the API docs, I would suggest you use the  example and edit it to your API specs